# Bootstrap MaxCDN not working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've visited a few bootstrap sites today and they all don't seem to loading the stylesheet. I checked my own sites all seemed okay apart from one because I hadn't linked a local copy of bootstrap as well.

So does anyone know if the bootstrap CSS has been moved from its current location or is it simply a case the CDN isn't working altogether?

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Seems to be working for me (at least right now)

Comment: when i go directly to the stylesheet link above I get a 'This webpage is not available' in chrome, strange that its working for you though

Comment: I also have the same issue intermittently (now May 2020), it's very strange, our web apps use this and sometimes they fail to load, then refresh and they work OK (most of the time), sometimes repeated fails.  Seems very weird, if it's not on their end, I have had issue with my local ISP blocking specific URLs / IPs, had to contact them and ask for a flush of my local area for that site and then it was fixed / accessible again.  Not sure if that's what's going on here, but nobody else seems to have this issue like I (/we) do... Works fine thru kproxy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me. You can check if it works for you:

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with CDN and now it's work for me.